# String given should get reversed using recursive function

Tags: c++, string, pointers, recursion

I am writing the code in which the string given should get reversed using recursive function and size() is used to calculate the size of the string, but it is giving an error

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int reverse(string);
int main()  
{  
    string str = "Reverse a string";//given string  
    reverse(str);
    return 0;  
}  
int reverse(string str)  
{
    if(str.size() == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return(reverse(str+1));
}
```

Comment: How come you think that it can reverse a string ?

Comment: Why not just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)? One line of code and you are done.

Comment: Reading the error and fixing what it tells you is wrong can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in the code.

1. You are doing (str+1) // This is error. Adding 1 to string doesn't mean anything.
2. What does it mean to return int. ?

This is how it should be

```
void reverse(string str)  
{  
    if(str.size() == 0) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 
    reverse(str.substr(1)); 
    cout << str[0]; 
}
```